# Nothing shows up in the terminal when password is required for sudo installation

Tags: command-line, keyboard, 22.04, sudo, password

I am a new Ubuntu user and calendar command does not work on my Ubuntu so I install sudo, but it asks for a password. When I try to type the password nothing shows up in the terminal except for a new line when I press the Enter key.

[image]

Comment: When you enter your password; nothing shows on your screen so as to prevent someone from looking over your shoulder & knowing what you entered as your password. This is done for security purposes, but your keystrokes are understood & acted upon until you press enter; despite you not seeing any characters (or even a "*" or "***" as that still lets people count how many keys you hit!)

Comment: Thanks, I understand..

Comment: @FatimaAli This is a privacy feature; it is just how Linux behaves.